# How can I stop the Program making new sheets, if this sheets (IGeneral,IInput,IResult) already exist?

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code goes through all excel files in the folder and checks if some specific sheets exist. but if I run the code 2nd time, it creates new sheets. How can I make it stop?

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim CurrentSheetName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
    myExtension = "*.xls*"

    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    Do While myFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        DoEvents
        CurrentSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name         
        Sheets.Add    

        On Error Resume Next     

        ActiveSheet.Name = "IGeneral"               
        CurrentSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
        Sheets(CurrentSheetName).Select
        Sheets.Add      

        On Error Resume Next   

        ActiveSheet.Name = "IInput"         
        Sheets(CurrentSheetName).Select
        CurrentSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
        Sheets.Add    

        On Error Resume Next     

        ActiveSheet.Name = "IResult"            
        Sheets(CurrentSheetName).Select                    

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True              

        DoEvents
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you use `On Error Resume Next` wrong. This line hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur. With this line you just close your eyes if anything goes wrong. Therefore remove `On Error Resume Next` completely and fix your errors. • You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • Also using `GoTo` is a very bad approach that you should avoid at any cost (unless it is used for an error handler).

Comment: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: @ITDev do you want to stop the program if a sheet exists or go to next line if sheet  IGeneral exists

Comment: @Dorian the Program should ignore every file that already has all 3( IGeneral, IInput, and IResult) and then the Program should close after checking everything.

Comment: @ITDev hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57274605/11167163) will Answer to your question, Please do not hesitate to give me **feedbacks**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if a sheet exists, and do *something* whether or not it is/isn't there, then you just need to determine if there's an error when you evaluate the first cell in the named sheet, e.g.:

```
If IsError(Evaluate("IGeneral!A1")) AND IsError(Evaluate("IInput!A1")) AND IsError(Evaluate("IResult!A1")) Then 'IsError returns boolean
    'Do something when there is an error (>=1 sheets DO NOT exist)
Else
    'Do something when there is no error (all sheets DO exist)
End If
```

Regarding your general coding, please review @Pᴇʜ 's comments below the post as there is a lot of important and useful info there.

---

**Edit1:**  Adding in sheet names (IGeneral, IInput, and IResult)

Your entire other bit of code could even go into the `True` scenario so it only runs if one/any of those sheets do not exist.